# Inheritance of entities in docbook files

Tags: xml, docbook, xinclude, xpointer

I am having some problems referencing some text from my xml files.

I have some xml documents (docbook 5.0 documents).

They all include a specific part from another xml file like this:

```
<xi:include href="path/to/myFile.xml" 
            xpointer="element(IDofSection)"/>
```

The referenced section has entities (like `$productname;`), that should be declared in the referencing document.

When I declare those entities in the referencing xml file, the referenced xml file does not inherit those entities.

I have searched all over the net but haven't found any solutions for this problem.
Is what I'm doing in principle possible with xinclude? If not, how can I manage this problem with another techniques?

Comment: I don't think it can work. See the third bullet here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ModularDoc.html#XincludeTextEntities.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done through an [entities file](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ModularEntities.html).

In this question [DocBook macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600827/docbook-macros) is an [example shown of the entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600827/docbook-macros/2640688#2640688) solution.